# Java ArrayList.add overwriting values

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

have this class

```
 public class Taxonomia {

    private static ArrayList<String> hijas;
    private static String padre;

    public Taxonomia (String p, ArrayList<String> h){
        hijas = h;
        padre = p;
        }

}
```

used in another class like this:

```
public class TablaSimbolica {

private static ArrayList<Taxonomia> taxonomias = new ArrayList<Taxonomia>();

public static void addTaxonomica(){

    System.out.println("enter value: ");
    String padre = Entrada.read(); //reads input and returns String
    System.out.println("entre value comma separated: ");
    String reemplazado = Entrada.read();
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(reemplazado.split("\\s*,\\s*")));
    Taxonomia t = new Taxonomia (padre, items);
    taxonomias.add(t);  

}
```

when called from the main simple as this (print its just a for...)

```
TablaSimbolica.addTaxonomica();
TablaSimbolica.addTaxonomica();
TablaSimbolica.printTax();
```

all the objects are the same, and i cant figure out where it is im missing the creation of a new object or something like that. thanks in advance!

Comment: only one value of static variable can exists at a time. leave the unnecessary static out and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class variables in the `Taxonomia` class are `static`, meaning only one of each for the entire class, no matter how many instances.

Make it one per instance by removing `static`.  Change

```
private static ArrayList<String> hijas;
private static String padre;
```

to

```
private ArrayList<String> hijas;
private String padre;
```